# Issue with Angular 10 / Nativescript 7 npm run ios --device

Tags: nativescript

I recently migrated an angular 10 project to nativescript 7 and have successfully rendered the app using npm run ios or npm run android.

The problem I am facing now is when I run "npm run ios" the ios emulator automatically always displays an ipad air 3rd gen. After looking at the documentation I tried to use the --device parameter with npm run ios (i.e. npm run ios --device "iPhone 8" but have run into issues when trying to do so I get the following error:

"The input is not valid sub-command for 'run' command."

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated so I can start deciding which devices I wanna work with.

Cheers!

Comment: Use ns instead of npm. Npm run iOS is just sugar for ns run ios. Once you’re using ns run ios you can add the —device flag.

Answer (score 0):

From spotlight search, try to write “Simulator”, which will most likely start an iPad. Go to “File->Open Simulator” and pick an iPhone. Once that has started, close the iPad and run
ns devices list

That should yield something like

```
┌───┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ # │ Device Name        │ Platform │ Device Identifier                    │ Type     │ Status    │ Connection Type │
│ 1 │ iPhone 8           │ iOS      │ E3270BFF-79A5-44A9-8119-5A398A3EA7CB │ Emulator │ Connected │ Local           │
└───┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘
```

then run

`ns run ios --no-hmr --device E3270BFF-79A5-44A9-8119-5A398A3EA7CB`

(the command needs the device id, not the device name)